# How to use a WebApi in combination with a redirect uri with a GET response? ASP.NET MVC, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am new to StackOverflow so if there is a right answer to my question below, I just didnt know what to look for..

I am currently working on a call to a API which works in the following matter:

1. Send specific parameters to a specific URI which also has the
   redirect URI. (done)
2. The response is send with an authorization code to the redirect
   URI.
3. The authorization code is send in a POST to get the access token
   and refresh token.
4. Response gives `AccessToken` and `RefreshToken`. Access data through API.

Yet I am stuck on step 2. I think I am stuck on the part where I made a new API controller but the controller doesn't work like the standard controller. So my question is how to make the URI work with the new controller and did I miss anything in how to make controller work properly.

code controller:

```
namespace ...Connection.Controllers
{
    public class ...Controller : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> GetAuthorizationCode(string code)
        {
            AuthorizationCode AuthCode = new AuthorizationCode();
            AuthCode.code = code;

            Console.WriteLine(code);

            return new string[] { };
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: The following happens, whenever i call the url like api/controller/getauthorizationcode?code=.. it returns that it doesnt exist. How do I make it exist? is it a routing problem?

Comment: Your route template `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",` does not expect the action name so it **will** say it cant find that URL. It is a routing issue. review the desired URL and update the expected routes to match

Comment: Thanx, its fixed!
Had to change the url path to: api/{controller}/{code}&{state}&{session_state}
and then in the controller: 
public void GetAuthorizationCode(string code, string state, string session_state) 
And then write it to the model